# How to add webhook_url in Stripe?

Tags: url, webhooks

I am using Stripe for payment in my project. I am not able to set the "webhook URL". In the docs it says that we should click on add_URL link in account_settings. But when I open account_settings, I don't find any link to add URL.
Is there any alternative way how I can set the webhook_URL?

Answer (score 0):

If you are logged in to the Stripe dashboard, look in the upper right for your user name.  Click that, then select Account Settings.  The screen will show some icons with names like General, Team, etc.  Click the one labeled "Webhooks," and then you will see the Add URL button.